# remove duplicate values from json data

Tags: jquery, json

I have a json data like this:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5306e7fd80b1027ad2653db4"),
  "testada": "ecom",
  "id": "27" 

} {
  "_id": ObjectId("5306e81880b1027ad2653db5"),
  "testada": "alorta",
  "id": "27" 
} {
  "_id": ObjectId("5306e81880b1027ad2653db6"),
  "testada": "france24",
  "id": "23" 
}
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5306e81880b1027ad2653db6"),
  "testada": "seloger",
  "id": "23" 
}
```

From this I have to remove one duplicate entry with `id:27`, the same as case `id:23`
my resulting `json` looks as follows:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5306e81880b1027ad2653db5"),
  "testada": "alorta",
  "id": "27" 
} {
  "_id": ObjectId("5306e81880b1027ad2653db6"),
  "testada": "france24",
  "id": "23" 
}
```

how it is possible

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/wtXx4/)</kbd>

```
var arr = [], //to collect id values 
    collection = []; //collect unique object

$.each(json_all, function (index, value) {
    if ($.inArray(value.id, arr) == -1) { //check if id value not exits than add it
        arr.push(value.id);//push id value in arr
        collection.push(value); //put object in collection to access it's all values
    }
});
console.log(collection); //you can access it values like collection[index].keyName
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the object collection from JSON string using JSON.parse("jsonstring") in which you can iterate and get the non duplicate items

```
var objColl = JSON.parse("JSON string");
var categories = [];

$.each(objColl, function(index, value) {
    if ($.inArray(value.category, categories)==-1) {
        categories.push(value.category);
    }
});
```